# How do I make a program think it was built under a different directory with cmake while cross-compiling?

Tags: cmake, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am trying to cross-compile a web server (Monkey-Server). My host environment is an Ubuntu 64 bit and the target environment is an has an arm architecture. All the dependencies are available in the folder.There is an option to make install too, but I thought building it locally on my host machine transferring the folder over to the embedded system was a smart move. I am able to compile successfully and run the web server on the target system, but it complains that it is not able to find the config file. The web server looks for the config file in the path where it was compiled on the host machine.

Example: It tries to open a folder that only exist on the host machine

> ERROR: Cannot find/open /home/username/src/camera_root/monkey-server/conf/

But it should actually be looking for the config file in

> /monkey-server/conf/

This is what my toolchain file looks like

```
Set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  /home/username/src/compilerdir/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc)

#SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/username/src/camera_root)
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/username/src/camera_root)
```

As you can see at the bottom of my toolchain file I have tried to set both sysroot and find_root_path without luck.

When I tried the SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/username/src/camera_root) line I was unable to compile because the C compiler was unable to compile a simple test program.

How do I help the web server find it's own config file?

Comment: Which config file to load should not be something you need to decide at build time.  Just figure out how to pass the correct path as an argument when launching the program.  Most programs support a `--help` option to tell you this sort of usage information.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That's what I thought too, but all I/O operations the server does is to the host path. I can for example see the paths to the log directory, in the config file is wrong. I fear that the web server will not work correctly because a lot of paths are incorrect.

Comment: Usually cross-compiling for non-host target involves **installing** with *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* suited for the **target** machine. But `make install` on host machine is replaced with `make DISTDIR=<...> install` or even `cpack` usage. This works for projects which adjust themselves on *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* directory. However, your project seems to adjust itself on source and build directories (I see no *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* usage in it).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for looking in to this. I have managed to get the server up and running by tracking down a lot of config-files and altering the paths in them. I have noticed there is a configure script that has a --prefix command. Do you think using this will help me?

Comment: If configurate script you have found passes `CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_*` variables to CMake, it could help.

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and the OP has probably moved on by now, but for anyone else with the same problem, the Monkey has a --configdir and a --configserver switch to set the location of the configuration files as a workaround for this problem.